# greenDAO: can I use gen folder in android-project?

Tags: android, orm, greendao

I'd like to use greenDAO for my project. Will there be any problems, if I use the folder 'gen' as generation target? 'gen' is generated by the ADT for working the the R.java files?

Answer (score 0):

One major drawback is, that the `gen`-Folder will be deleted when you clean the project. So you have to run the Generator-Project again.

Are there more pros and cons?